# How can I evaluate this function in Mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am very new to Mathematica. Today I have got my license. Can someone help me to evaluate the following expression in Mathematica. I want find the values of $P$ for different $n$

$S=129$;

$F_l(\omega)=\Bigg[h[S]+2\sum_{n=1}^{S-2}h[S-n]\cos\left(n\left(\omega-\frac{2\pi l}{M}\right)\right)\Bigg]$

$\Phi (f)=(F_0(f))^2$

$P(n)=\int_{(n-0.5)f_s}^{(n+0.5)f_s}\Phi(f)df$

Here $f_s=10e6$ and $h$ is given below

$h=[0,0.00015583,0.0006215,0.0013871,0.0024371,0.0037496,0.0052973,0.0070468,0.0089597,0.010992,0.013097,0.015221,0.017309,0.019301,0.021136,0.02275,0.024078,0.025055,0.025613,0.025687,0.025214,0.02413,0.022376,0.019895,0.016635,0.012548,0.0075906,0.001726,-0.005076,-0.012839,-0.021579,-0.031303,-0.042011,-0.053693,-0.06633,-0.079894,-0.094347,-0.10964,-0.12571,-0.1425,-0.15992,-0.17789,-0.1963,-0.21505,-0.23402,-0.25308,-0.2721,-0.29093,-0.30941,-0.32739,-0.3447,-0.36117,-0.37662,-0.39087,-0.40373,-0.41501,-0.42452,-0.43207,-0.43747,-0.44053,-0.44106,-0.43887,-0.43378,-0.42562,-0.41421,-0.3994,-0.38103,-0.35895,-0.33302,-0.30313,-0.26916,-0.23102,-0.1886,-0.14186,-0.090721,-0.035152,0.024872,0.08936,0.1583,0.23167,0.30941,0.39147,0.47777,0.56819,0.66263,0.76095,0.86299,0.96858,1.0775,1.1896,1.3047,1.4224,1.5425,1.6649,1.7891,1.9149,2.042,2.1701,2.2988,2.4279,2.5569,2.6855,2.8135,2.9403,3.0658,3.1894,3.3109,3.43,3.5462,3.6592,3.7687,3.8744,3.9759,4.073,4.1653,4.2525,4.3344,4.4108,4.4814,4.5459,4.6042,4.656,4.7013,4.7399,4.7716,4.7964,4.8142,4.8249,4.8284,4.8249,4.8142,4.7964,4.7716,4.7399,4.7013,4.656,4.6042,4.5459,4.4814,4.4108,4.3344,4.2525,4.1653,4.073,3.9759,3.8744,3.7687,3.6592,3.5462,3.43,3.3109,3.1894,3.0658,2.9403,2.8135,2.6855,2.5569,2.4279,2.2988,2.1701,2.042,1.9149,1.7891,1.6649,1.5425,1.4224,1.3047,1.1896,1.0775,0.96858,0.86299,0.76095,0.66263,0.56819,0.47777,0.39147,0.30941,0.23167,0.1583,0.08936,0.024872,-0.035152,-0.090721,-0.14186,-0.1886,-0.23102,-0.26916,-0.30313,-0.33302,-0.35895,-0.38103,-0.3994,-0.41421,-0.42562,-0.43378,-0.43887,-0.44106,-0.44053,-0.43747,-0.43207,-0.42452,-0.41501,-0.40373,-0.39087,-0.37662,-0.36117,-0.3447,-0.32739,-0.30941,-0.29093,-0.2721,-0.25308,-0.23402,-0.21505,-0.1963,-0.17789,-0.15992,-0.1425,-0.12571,-0.10964,-0.094347,-0.079894,-0.06633,-0.053693,-0.042011,-0.031303,-0.021579,-0.012839,-0.005076,0.001726,0.0075906,0.012548,0.016635,0.019895,0.022376,0.02413,0.025214,0.025687,0.025613,0.025055,0.024078,0.02275,0.021136,0.019301,0.017309,0.015221,0.013097,0.010992,0.0089597,0.0070468,0.0052973,0.0037496,0.0024371,0.0013871,0.0006215,0.00015583]$

Comment: For a start did you run with a smaller $h$ size?

Comment: It's adviseable to try what you could first with your brand new copy of Mathematica.

Comment: @DipankarNarayanan please look at the answers to your previous related question and as suggested attempt your own answer...MSE I am sure would help with specific difficulties that arise

Comment: show what you have tried so folks can see where you are stuck. One hint, dont try to work with subscripts, define `F` simply like:   `F[ l_,w_]:=` ..

Comment: Welcome to the world of Mathematica! Though I applaud your choice of CAS, I'd suggest you read some introductory texts on the language. Your post is like buying a car and then asking on the Internet how to drive.

Answer (score 4):

I am a slightly confused by the equation for Fl[w] as it has a M term in it. However, since you are evaluating it with l = zero, that term drops out so I will ignore it in this answer.

First step I think is good for this problem is to set h equal to a list:

```
h = {0, 0.00015583, 0.0006215, ..., 0.00015583};
```

You can then view it by using the ListPlot function

```
ListPlot[h]
```

The mid-point is 128 and you have set S = 129, one point past the mid-point. I will use lower case letters for everything (good practice) so I will set:

```
s = 129;
```

The semi-colon is not required but suppresses the output.

To define the function Fl[w] I will only use w as l is zero:

```
f[w_] := h[[s]] + 
  2*Total[Map[h[[s - 1 - #]] Cos[# w] &, Range[1, s - 2]]]
```

You will need help in order to understand this expression. Let's break it down.

First, double brackets are used to indicate list (or array) indices. h[[s]] means index "s" in the list h. This takes getting used to. Thus h[[2]] is the value 0.00015583 and h[[s]]=h[[129]]=4.8284.

Secondly, the inner part that starts with Map is:

```
Map[h[[s - 1 - #]] Cos[# w] &, Range[1, s - 2]]
```

This is a bit scary at first. It uses what is known as a functional programming style rather than what most new users are accustomed to, procedural style.

This is interpreted as follows.

Range[1,s-2] is the list {1,2,3, ..., 127}.

What we are going to do is to produce a new list where we replace # in the expression h[[s - 1 - #]] Cos[# w] with each of the numbers in the range of 1 to 127. Thus for example, the second entry in the list would be:

```
h[[129-1-2]] Cos[2 w]
```

This will produce a new list of 127 results. The function Total will add them together.

Lastly we multiply it by 2 and add h[[s]] to the result.

You can plot it by selecting a plot range, I will do it for zero to 10.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

To define your phi[w] function I used:

```
phi[w_] := f[w]^2
```

The intermediate step of creating f[w] is not needed but it makes it a bit easier to read.

You can also plot it using

```
Plot[phi[w], {w, 0, 10}]
```

I suspect that there is some unit confusion as when I plot phi[w] with the limits 0.5*fs to 1.5*fs (with fs = 10^6) the plot doesn't look nearly as clear as the lower range (0 to 10). Nevertheless since phi[w] is simply a function you can use the Integrate function to compute the definite integral. I used prob as the name of the function rather than P.

```
prob[n_] := Integrate[f[w], {w, (n - 0.5)*fs, (n + 0.5)*fs}]
```

When I evaluate this with n = 1 it takes quite a long time but comes up with the result:

```
prob[1]
4.8284*10^6
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your detailed explanation. Why did you write prob[n_] := Integrate[f[w], {w, (n - 0.5)*fs, (n + 0.5)*fs}] instead of prob[n_] := Integrate[Phi[w], {w, (n - 0.5)*fs, (n + 0.5)*fs}]. However, when I do so, I do not get any value, instead I get an expression. How to resolve this?